# SELECT Table From Other Table

Tags: sql

how to select table from select other table ?

Table1

```
ID| Name |

1 | Henry
2 | Dony
```

Table2

```
ID| Addres|

1 | London
2 | Texas
```

I have select ID table2 From Select table1, like below :

```
SELECT ID From Table2 Where Select ID From Table1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a `JOIN` to do so:

```
SELECT ID FROM Table2 AS T2
INNER JOIN Table1 AS T1
ON T2.ID=T1.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Christos is totally right, you can just use an `INNER JOIN` to join the two tables. Basically, what this will do is combine both tables, returning only those values from where your specified match key exists. So if you have an ID from table 1, and it isn't in table 2, then you won't see that ID in the query Christos specified. You can use a `LEFT JOIN` on the command above to get ALL ID's from the T1 table (or a `RIGHT JOIN` to get all ID's from T2).

Good luck!